# facing issue to build a trigger on Opportunity to create a task

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger, code

Requirement-
I need to create a task on the opportunity when stage changes to Need analysis.
but if a task with description already presents with 'Need analysis' for this opportunity then no need to create a new task.

I have to build a code but stuck at how to check if the task is present for that oppo with need analysis description
Please suggest
below is what I am trying

```
public class OpprtunityHelper {
    public static void taskOnOpportunity(List<opportunity>oppList){
        set<Id> oppId =new set<Id>();
        for(opportunity op:oppList) {
            if(op.StageName =='Needs analysis'){
                oppId.add(op.id);
            }

        }
        list<task> taskList =  new List<task>([select id,WhatId,Description from task where Whatid in:oppId]);
        system.debug('tasklist==>'+taskList);
        map<id,task> taskmap = new map<id,task>();
        for(task ts:taskList) {
            taskmap.put(ts.whatid,ts);
        }   
        List<task> tinsert = new list<task>();
        map<opportunity,integer> mapcount =new map<opportunity,integer>();
        for(opportunity op:oppList) {
            integer count=0;
            for(task t:taskmap.values()) {
                if(taskmap.get(op.id)!=null && taskmap.get(op.id).description!='Need analysis') {
                    count++;
                }

            }
            mapcount.put(op,count);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear what status value you really need, `Needs analysis` or `Need analysis`, I assumed `Needs analysis`.

After you query the tasks for the Opportunities, check if any the tasks description is = 'Need Analysis', if yes, remove its WhatId i.e. Opportunity Id from the `oppId` set.

```
public class OpprtunityHelper {
    public static void taskOnOpportunity(List<opportunity>oppList){
        Set<Id> oppIdSet =new Set<Id>();
        for(opportunity op:oppList) {
            if(op.StageName == 'Needs analysis'){
                oppIdSet.add(op.id);
            }
        }

        for(Task task: [SELECT id,WhatId,Description FROM Task WHERE Whatid IN :oppIdSet]){
            if(task.Description == 'Needs analysis'){
                system.debug('remove');
                oppIdSet.remove(task.WhatId);
            }
        }

        // write your logic to create a task here.
        List<task> tasks = new list<task>();
        for(Id oppId: oppIdSet){
            Task taskObj = new Task();
            taskObj.whatId = oppId;
            taskObj.Description = 'Needs analysis';
            tasks.add(taskObj);
        }

        insert tasks;
    }
}
```

Also I would suggest to check if the value is changed from something else to 'Needs analysis'.

Comment: thanks,rahul.It works

Comment: do u see any issue with bulkification? anyways will run and check code

Comment: @sandy I think it should run just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can write below code:

```
public class OpprtunityHelper {
    public static void taskOnOpportunity(List<opportunity>oppList){
        set<Id> oppId =new set<Id>();
        for(opportunity op:oppList) {
            if(op.StageName =='Needs analysis'){
                oppId.add(op.id);
            }

        }
        list<task> taskList =  new List<task>([select id,WhatId,Description from task where Whatid in:oppId]);
        system.debug('tasklist==>'+taskList);
        map<id,task> taskmap = new map<id,task>();
        set<Id> oppIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        for(task ts:taskList) {
            if(! ts.Description.contains('Need analysis')){
                 taskmap.put(ts.whatid,ts);
                 oppIdSet.add(ts.WhatId);
            }

        }   


        List<task> tinsert = new list<task>();

        for(Id idva : oppIdSet){
            Task ts = new Task();
            ts.WhatId = idva;
            ts.Description = 'Desc';

            tinsert.add(ts);
        }

        insert tinsert;


    }
}
```

Comment: its not working,..Consider the situation when there is no task assigned to opportunity then it should create new task ,but nothing is happening here